# How can I host an iOS IPA on a SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: ios, sharepoint-2013, ipa, ios-enterprise

I'm trying to distribute an Enterprise signed iOS App to employees via a secured SharePoint site but it doesn't want to work.

When clicking the specialized link to the manifest.plist file I get the prompt `Open this page in "App Store"?` I click "Open" and am then prompted for credentials. I enter my creds and click OK, then get asked `sub.domain.com would like to install "My App"`. I click Install and then get

**Unable to Download App**

> "My App" could not be downloded at this time.

Done | Retry

Clicking Retry just brings the same prompt up.

Any suggestions?

I've made sure of the following:

1. I'm using absolute URLs in the link and the manifest.plist file - I found relative URLs don't work
2. The URL contains no spaces - a space (%20) seems to cause problems
3. All files are checked in and published as major versions
4. All files are in the /site/SiteAssets/ folder, which don't really require publishing
5. The site contains a valid SSL certificate

A colleague and I figure this is caused by SharePoint storing content as BLOBs in a backend database and not serving up files directly, but doesn't DropBox do the same thing? Even with DropBox's dl.dropbox.com links I would figure they're store somewhere in a CMS.

Comment: Is your manifest, .IPA etc available without authentication? I.e does it require session from Safari?

Comment: It **does** require authentication, usually picking up the browser session (Safari/Chrome/etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You say that content is served in a backend database and NOT as files directly. That, probably, means that your manifest, .IPA files are available under web-site authentication?! If, so, please note:

That although you open a `itms-services` in Safari, your manifest.plist and .IPA are fetched directly by device, that means no cookies etc, no authentication... it is not a browser.

Make it available without any auth procedures, it might help,

Also please check you use right Mime-Types for .plist and .ipa
`application/x-plist` and `application/octet-stream` respectively.

Comment: Thanks Ilnar. I'll look into the MIME types. In the meantime we published the PLIST and IPA to an SSL secured Apache server and appended the group login credentials inside `itms-services` URL parameter like this: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://user:passwd@www.example.com/my.plist` Ideally we'll want this fully contained in SharePoint.

Comment: Ilnar - We're using SharePoint online (aka. o365) which unfortunately doesn't currently support custom MIME types - https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/232241